# How do I create a completely blank HTML or ASPX page?

Tags: 2013, publishing-site

I want to create a completely blank page where I can put anything on it. I don't want the ribbon or anything. Is this possible in SharePoint? It's a publishing site.

Answer (score 1):

Simply create an HTML file on your desktop, with any content you like, and then upload it to any SharePoint document library. You can create the page manually with Notepad, or with any HTML editor (even with Word, but noone will then guarantee the generated HTML is clean!).
Add a link to the file somewhere in your navigation, and you're done!

Comment: Will .html-files automatically work? Or must they be [tricked](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11504160)?

Comment: This works, but I had to make it a .aspx file.

Comment: Yup, I forgot about the "strict" Browser File Handling setting, you're right eirikb. The link you mention would solve that. matt: you can use .html if you follow instructions from the link posted by eirikb.